# Add automatically anonymous properties to routeValues which is object in ASP.NET MVC4 ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use this [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method in order to generate method.

`LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)`

Sot the 4th parameter is an Object which contains anonymous properties, used for routes.

It is possible to append/add automatically new anonymous properties to existing routeValues which is Object ?

If yes, how ?

Let's assume that I have a method:

```
public void Test( ref object currentRouteValues, string newValue)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue)){
       // add a custom property here to currentRouteValues
       // something like: (is wrong but I don't know how to proceed)
       currentRouteValues = new { currentRouteValues, myCustoProperty = newValue };
    }
}
```

How to do that automatically for above method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would answer your question.

[Merging anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754967/merging-anonymous-types)

If  you simply want to extract the data it would be something like this.

```
        Object o = new { var1 = "the first var", var2 = "the second var" };

        System.Type type = o.GetType();

        foreach (var i in type.GetProperties())
        {
            Console.Write(i.GetValue(o));
        }
```

But for merging, look at the link above.